# 2 lines mean it won't run on iPad

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.2

We have a project that runs fine on OS4 but we're having problems getting it to run on iPad 3.2.

Base SDK is 4.0 and Deployment target is 3.2.

The code crashes on the iPad simulator (and device) before it has even started, with the error

> "Data Formatters temporarily
>   unavailable"

It seems to run okay if I take 2 lines out...

```
AVURLAsset* asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:assetURL options:options];
```

and

```
export = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];
```

I branch according to what OS is present so that these lines **never get reached** when on a 3.2 device (I know they are OS4), but just them being there at all makes the thing crash out before it even begins.

Any ideas?
Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If those lines are never reached on the iPad, you may be encountering a problem due to not weak-linking the AVFoundation framework (and potentially others).  Because AVURLAsset and AVAssetExportSession don't exist as symbols in 3.2, your application may be crashing on startup on that older OS.

I describe how to weak-link a framework in response to a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618889/universal-iphone-ipad-application-debug-compilation-error-for-iphone-testing) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618889/universal-iphone-ipad-application-debug-compilation-error-for-iphone-testing/2622027#2622027).

Comment: Spot on Brad! That fixed it straight away.

Comment: specifying deployment target to some earlier version wouldn't automatically weak link symbols which don't exist in that version?

Comment: @pqnet - With the iOS 4.2 SDK and a target of iOS 3.1 and later, you can now use per-class weak linking instead of framework-based weak linking: http://www.marco.org/2010/11/22/supporting-older-versions-of-ios-while-using-new-apis .  I'm not sure what the Mac runtimes and SDK versions are that support this as well.  For a target older than 3.1, you'd still need to weak link the framework.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, "Data Formatters temporarily unavailable" is a GDB message, it's **not** why your application crashes. More information regarding this message can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573477/data-formatters-temporarily-unavailable).

You need to check the availability of classes during runtime (not compile-time) if you want to write code that runs on both iOS 3.0 and 4.0.

You can do this using the `NSClassFromString` function like this:

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"AVURLAsset")) {
    // 4.0 code using AVURLAsset goes here
} else {
    // 3.0 code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (or similar):

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < 40000
  // code for iOS below 4.0
#else
  // code for iOS 4.0
#endif
```

Stolen from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019234/how-to-split-code-for-ios-3-0-and-ios-3-2-so-i-can-use-mpmovieplayerviewcontrolle).

Comment: I think he will have to upload a single binary to run on 4.0 and 3.2, so the check will have to be at run time, not compile time.

Comment: Indeed - the same binary for both. The lines I quoted are never even reached if running on 3.2 as I already branch off. What puzzles me is that their inclusion means that the binary will not even start on 3.2.